# How to get value of URL query parameter with dynamic name?

Tags: javascript

I need to extract the value of a query parameter in a URL, but the parameter changes on each page.

For example, I want to get the color variable, but it always changes based on the productID. In this case it is 'dwvar_2000440926_color' but for another product it will be 'dwvar_545240926_color'. _color stays consistent, so I'd like to key off that:

https://www.example.com/us/2000440926.html?dwvar_2000440926_color=02

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Basic regular expression](https://regexper.com/#%2Fdwvar_%5Cd%2B_color%3D%28%5B%5E%26%5D%2B%29%2F) would work

```js
const myURL = new URL("https://www.example.com/us/2000440926.html?dwvar_2000440926_color=02")

console.log(myURL.search.match(/_color=([^&]+)/)[1]);

// more specfic
console.log(myURL.search.match(/dwvar_\d+_color=([^&]+)/)[1]);
```

Comment: Works great- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex. Based on the description of the URL behavior you described you could do something like this:

```
const url = new URL("https://www.example.com/us/2000440926.html?dwvar_2000440926_color=02");

// Now url.search contains your query parameters.
// We gonna apply the regex on it to capturing the color id
let matches = url.search.match(/dwvar_\d+_color=(\d+)/)

// `matches` now contains the captured groups
console.log(matches[1])
// log : 02
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 1) you want to do this on the client side 2) the color param always begins with `dwvar` as shown in your example and 3) that there is never more than one dwvar param, you can use the following javascript:

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
searchParams.forEach((param_value, param_name) => {
  if (param_name.indexOf('dwvar') == 0) {
    console.log(param_value)
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.location.search.slice(1).split('&').reduce((acc, it) => {
  const [key, val] = it.split('=');
  return {
  ...acc,
      [key]: val,
  };
}, {});
```